# Consistency of an unbiased estimator with $v(\hat\alpha_{n})\to0$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: statistics

Let $\hat{\alpha_{n}}$ be based on i.i.d sample of n measurements.

Show: If $\hat{\alpha_{n}}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\alpha$  and its variance obeys, $v(\hat\alpha_{n}) \to0$ as $n \to\infty$, then $\hat{\alpha_{n}}$ is consistent for  $\alpha$.

I believe an argument can be made using the MSE=$v(\hat\alpha_{n})=\frac{\sigma^2_\alpha}{n}(1-\frac{n-1}{N-1})$
where the bias $= 0$, but I don't understand how to construct a rigorous argument.
It would make sense that the variance will continue to shrink around the mean as n increases.

Consistency is defined as such: for$\ \epsilon >0 ,P(\left|\hat{\alpha_{n}}-\alpha\right |>\epsilon)\to 0\ as\ n\to \infty$

How would one prove this to be true?
Thank you,
boba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Chebyshev's inequality, $$P \left(|\hat{\alpha_n}-\alpha| >\epsilon\right)\leq \frac{v(\hat{\alpha_n})}{\epsilon^2}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P \left(|\hat{\alpha_n}-\alpha| >\epsilon\right)\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{v(\hat{\alpha_n})}{\epsilon^2}=0$$

Comment: Thank you, this helps alot!